# Watermark in PdfCreator

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, pdfcreator

I printed a document in Word to PdfCreator with a watermark.  The word DRAFT looks good in Word, but PdfCreator prints the watermark with a tile pattern and is not smooth.  Anyway to make PdfCreator print the watermark properly?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Options -> Document -> first tab of properties -> mark
Delete the content of the "text of the mark" field

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Options" box of PDFCreator (Shortcut: Ctrl+O). Click on Formats > PDF on the left pane.

Under "Compression" tab, deselect "Compress text objects". Additionally, under "Colors" tab, select "Preserve Halftone Information".

Now click on "Save" and reprint your doc with PDFCreator.

Comment: I can't leave a comment for Mehper so I'll add it here. Thanks, but that didn't change the watermark.

Comment: @bruced, you've added a second account using a different email address -- if you can modify your (new) profile to use the matching email address I can merge the accounts, then you'll regain ownership of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semitransparency in Word.

Word 2013: Design tab > Watermark > Custom Watermark > uncheck **Semitransparent**.

Worked for me!